# Force Immutable Return in Typescript

Tags: typescript, types, immutability

Hello i want to know if its possible to stop overwriting a type so it stays immutable at compile time.

For example what i mean lets create an interface

```
interface freeze{
  frozen: boolean;
}
```

and a deep freeze function

```
function deepFreeze<T>(obj: T) {
  var propNames = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj);
  for (let name of propNames) {
    let value = (obj as any)[name];
    if (value && typeof value === "object") {
      deepFreeze(value);
    }
  }
  return Object.freeze(obj);
}
```

if i now make something like this

```
function shouldntWork(): freeze  //:freeze is what i want to be blocked as its wrong
{  
 let mutableFreeze: freeze = { frozen:false}
  let immutableFreeze = deepFreeze(mutableFreeze); 
  return immutableFreeze;
}
```

I know that this is not a bug but i wanna know if there is some kind of eslint rule that forces to not overwrite the type or something becaus if i would do something like this

```
function other()  {
  let something = shouldntWork();
  something.frozen = true;
  //will crash at runtime but want it to get blocked at compiletime
    console.log(something);
}
```

it will crash
But if i didnt had the :freeze it would infer the correct readonly type and would give me an error at compileTime.

here is Typescript playground
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noImplicitOverride=true#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAhlCEBeEDeBYAKGVSgHtsQAuZAI1NIBsI4QBuQgX0MKbGQGdSAWwgAxdFgjU0GbMgC8yHGnIQqqOA34QuBQjACuIBGGCkQAgBakDDACbgA6qSgBrABQBKSjMlLCxAHIvMiQ-JBQCsh2GAAO4rIQ7oIiCZKerMhB6GAGUBZhEewEuvpGJmYWpGCW0F7E+ETBEHwpLZagAOZR-Na2DmDObl7FxG01XQB0KhRRYFAGEKPIAPQrAO7ADAzICFBwvchwfAvgwCK0BnzrLHzAfGCkyJ0ttAykCK4Qdkd8CMKxLYtc4QILEf4gQRMSbvTrJYTtLoZTjcPQEQzGUzmaJxNLYAA8ABUAHzuUg0ABW1EJnn8TRCsTIsQAcnARPwogB5SkQEyTF5gTnrEAABSZ0DAAE9WeyyZTkU0YC5kO4QiA2ShSDBkIzSCyNfxaY1iMQQgA3TSLKJyilHDksSWeADa6pEAF1lsRgNr3BaGFaAGQB0KS2IQLXIP1W+Qx5AAInJFN5YDjRrBJpiEHiEmwvstEAVJuQumIJeQOTyFm5Sb5vlziYVpQI1VqUBGQA

Answer (score 1):

You could use a DeepReadOnly found here -> https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13923

Example here -> https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcxQJYFsMwwN1QF44BnGTAOwHM4AfOSgVywCNgp65WIIAbYAENKXJpQAmwAGYZKwcV2Z8+AWABQoSLATJUAEWDAwAJSHiIlPogA8AFQB8cIurhxbcUDGATSaTDjxCOAB+NzgALhcwz29xXwBBKChBG1kpDjgAVUdQgyNTQXNLRETkm2yIqLyTMwsrAHlWACtgAGMYO3t1TWh4WS8oKUFW-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-KRoDgbUjUoQDUABBcwBQk19RjVxv3dOB8BFcs+TQppmwnShEF1F58JZIEc0ojBAW1Wi+HogAyYSTmAIjBPoogZLgAAie9rhgOTyKiSi4Eva8bSkp0eNceF9LdD0vTgUD2iLDkbUU-UWzBfInhsBx-QlMMIygbMgA

Note don't set the return type on shouldntWork, so that Typescript can infer the read-only..

```
export type primitive = string | number | boolean | undefined | null
export type DeepReadonly<T> =
  T extends primitive ? T :
  T extends Array<infer U> ? DeepReadonlyArray<U> :
  DeepReadonlyObject<T>
export interface DeepReadonlyArray<T> extends ReadonlyArray<DeepReadonly<T>> {}
export type DeepReadonlyObject<T> = {
  readonly [P in keyof T]: DeepReadonly<T[P]>
}



interface freeze{
  frozen: boolean;
}

let someFreeze: freeze = {frozen: false}

function shouldntWork() {
  let tester = deepFreeze(someFreeze); 
  return tester;
}

function other()  {
  let something = shouldntWork();
  something.frozen = true;  //Cannot assign to 'frozen' because it is a read-only property.
  console.log(something);
}


function deepFreeze<T>(obj: T):DeepReadonly<T> {
  let propNames = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj);
  for (let name of propNames) {
    let value = (obj as any)[name];
    if (value && typeof value === "object") {
      deepFreeze(value);
    }
  }
  return Object.freeze(obj) as DeepReadonly<T>;
}

other();
```

Comment: also tried it with the deepreadonly type :p.

i know if i dont infer the type that typescript will return the correct type but for example something like this can happen pretty fast

let something : freeze = shouldntWork()

but i guess there is no possible way that typescript gives out a warning or something to stop this :/.

Comment: @DoNetApp  Sorry, not sure what your saying.  The Typescript playground I posted does give an error..

Comment: function other()  {
  let something: freeze = shouldntWork();
  something.frozen = true;  //No Error becaus type got 'wrongly' inferred also no warning
  console.log(something);
}

Comment: @DoNetApp  It does work, as seen on my Typescript example.  But I did notice the Link in my answer was broken, for some reason using the Link in SO seems broken here,.